# Обработка форм: передать текст в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Через `post` метод передаю из формы в базу текст итальянского. В этом языке есть одинарная кавычка. При отправке в базу говорит ошибку касательно этой одинарной кавычки. Обрабатываю `htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);`, но не помогает! Не могу понять как исправить это.

Comment: используйте PDO/mysqli [bindparam](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: @kiberpon, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте знаки препинания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$text = mysql_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']));
```

Если и это не помогло =), тогда так можно ( кривой способ))))

```
$text = str_replace("'", "\'", $_POST['text']);
```

Comment: а ещё лучше $text = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']));

Comment: огроменное спасибо)) все получанца))) только кинул на всякий случай в яндекс и всезнающий мне подсказал что эта функция устарела и не рекомендуется ей пользоваться и направил меня на путь истины ))) т.е. mysql_real_escape_string )))спасибо Вам ))

Comment: Путь истины - это placeholders, всякие *escape* - ерунда :)

Comment: хммм.. помыслим и над этим чудо-словом :)